# Disable plain text data storing in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain data stored in /var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData in plain text.
This data include Private Database data, created with transient arguments.
I wonder if there is any way to not store (at least the private) data in the 000001.log files present in each peer in the mentioned path above.
I tried to set all logging to ERROR, using FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC env var, but it doesn't seem to affect these files.

Using HLF Fabric v2.4 with levelDB.

Thank you.